# Vue.js method is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is some problem with methods, 
my component can't access to methods. May i need to pass methods like prop to component ?

here is my html:

```
<guests v-bind="guests"></guests>
```

here is component in my js file

```
var guestsComponent = Vue.component("guests", {
  props: ['adultCount', 'childCount'],
  template: `
    <div class="guests-total">
      <div>
      <a @click="decrementAdult"></a>
      <a @click="incrementAdult"></a>
      <input type="text" placeholder="adults"/> {{adultCount}}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
});
```

and here in the same js file my vue init and methods

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#search",
  components: {
    "guests": guestsComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      guests: {
        adultCount: 0,
        childCount: 0
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    decrementAdult() {
      this.guests.adultCount++
    },
    incrementAdult() {
      this.guests.adultCount--
    }
  }
});
```

I can access to data without problem when i use the props but i don't know how i can pass methods like props or this is needed?

here is error on console:

```
ReferenceError: decrementAdult is not defined
    at o.eval (eval at xa (vue.min.js:NaN), <anonymous>:3:88)
    at o.fn._render (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
    at o.eval (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
    at St.get (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
    at new St (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
    at o.hn.$mount (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
    at o.hn.$mount (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
    at init (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
    at eval (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
    at b (vue.min.js?f6b5:6)
```

Comment: You don't have a `decrementAdult` method in your `guests` component definition. Either move that method to the `guests` component or emit an event  from the child component (`<a @click="$emit('decrement')"></a>`) that the parent component can handle by calling that method (`<guests v-bind="guests" @decrement="decrementAdult"></guests>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `click` events are done in the child component `guests` you should emit an event to the parent component and handle it there like :

```
    ....
    <a @click="$emit('decrement-adult')"></a>
     ...
```

in the parent component do :

```
   <guests v-bind="guests" @decrement-adult="decrementAdult"></guests>
```

Comment: thanks its worked too:) but it will be like that @decrement-adult="decrementAdult()">

Comment: if you're not passing parameters the `()` are not needed

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar `'method1' is not defined` error from the following code section:

```
methods: {
    method1(){
      console.log("running method1()");
    },
    method2(){
      method1();
    },
    ...
```

The problem was that the reference to `method1()` should have included the `this` keyword like so:

```
export default {
  name: 'TuringMachine',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
  },
  methods: {
    method1(){
      console.log("running method1()");
    },
    method2(){
      this.method1();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.